# Use Domino web server hosts servlet, but it's built-in servlet api is too old

Tags: servlets, lotus-domino

according to [this guide](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/81c15cf1464d727585256c54004b850e?OpenDocument)! I run servlet successfully, but some of actions of the servlet failed, because they need servlet-api 2.5+ support. how can I use my own servlet-api library instead of domino web server's old version.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

David Taieb (software architect at IBM) stated in a [comment to a blog post](http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/08172011032738AMNHEART.htm):

> In 8.5.2, Domino introduced support for Equinox Http Service which allows you to create lightweight servlets registered via extension points. I say lightweight because these servlets are not run within the context of a traditional J2EE Web App with web.xml support. However, the Equinox Http Service lets you associate an http context to different servlets so that they share the same http session object.
>
> Starting in 8.5.3, Domino will start supporting the XPD Web Container which is a full fledged J2EE Web Container (although it does not support things like EJBs). With the XPD Web Container, you can transform almost any WAR into a WAB (Web Archive bundle) and run it in Domino.

You maybe also want to take a look at [Servlet Sample](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Servlet%20Sample) at OpenNTF.

Otherwise, please state the version of Domino, you are currently using.